# "left join" the results of glm to original file if there are missings in the model outcome?

Tags: r, left-join, glm, na

after creating a model with glm

```
model <- glm(data$y ~ data$x * data$z)
```

I need to create a dataset that includes the output of the glm and the original data for further processing

```
newdata <- data.frame(
                  data$id, 
                  data$y, #observed 
                  fitted(model), #expected
                  resid(model),
                  data$x,
                  data$z,
                  data$othervariable1,
                  data$othervariable2,
                  data$othervariable3
                  )
```

This runs perfectly well as long as glm produces as many records as the data file has. But if for any reason (mostly missing values) the model data has less records the join doesn't work:

> error in data.frame(....): arguments has differents counts of rows:
>   21, 18

`na.action = na.pass` in order to avoid missing values in glm didn't seem to work either

Is there a way to transport the unique identifier to the GLM output? Or is there a fancy function?(I'm sure there ism but I don't find it)

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265798/predict-glm-not-predicting-missing-values-in-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the situation `na.exclude` was made for.  See the Details section of `?residuals.glm`.  Essentially the residuals and fitted values will contain the NA values if you use `na.exclude`.

Example using the data from @Thomas answer:

```
fit1 = glm(y ~ x, data = dat)
length(residuals(fit1))
[1] 90

fit2 = glm(y ~ x, data = dat, na.action = na.exclude)
length(residuals(fit2))
[1] 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of the `na.action` attribute to the `model` element of your `glm` object. In the below example, I call the glm object `g` for clarity, to indicate that `model` is an element of `g`:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                  y = rbinom(100,1,.5))
dat$x[sample(1:100, 10, FALSE)] <- NA
g <- glm(y ~ x, data=dat)

# identify dropped observations
d <- attributes(g$model)$na.action

# store results back into original `dat` data.frame
dat$fitted <- NA
dat$fitted[-d] <- g$fitted
dat$resid <- NA
dat$resid[-d] <- g$resid
```

This correctly puts everything back where it's supposed to be:

```
> summary(dat)
       x                  y            fitted           resid        
 Min.   :-2.21470   Min.   :0.00   Min.   :0.2959   Min.   :-0.3842  
 1st Qu.:-0.56213   1st Qu.:0.00   1st Qu.:0.3317   1st Qu.:-0.3472  
 Median : 0.11391   Median :0.00   Median :0.3439   Median :-0.3317  
 Mean   : 0.08907   Mean   :0.38   Mean   :0.3444   Mean   : 0.0000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.69516   3rd Qu.:1.00   3rd Qu.:0.3581   3rd Qu.: 0.6412  
 Max.   : 2.40162   Max.   :1.00   Max.   :0.3928   Max.   : 0.7041  
 NA's   :10                        NA's   :10       NA's   :10
```

Comment: @user3782669 If you found the answer useful, please consider up-voting it and marking it as accepted (by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer) so that others know your issue has been resolved.